# Splitting a non comma separated string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a query that concatenates the values of two columns and returns a string as shown below:

```
423545(50),7568787(50),53654656,2021947(50),
```

Now i need to work on the individual numbers without the values in the brackets. I could rerun another query to retrieve the values but i am thinking it is more efficient to split the existing string instead of making another database call.

How can i split the above string to remove the values in brackets? I want to store the numbers in an ArrayList. 
The arrayList will contain  423545,7568787,53654656,2021947, (without the commas)

Note that not all columns will have the bracketed value - See third column
There could be a comma at the end of the string.

I can split it using `String.split()` if it was just with commas but i guess the above format requires a regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] list = str.split("(\\(\\d+\\))?,");
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/2DHBo3)**.

Comment: Probably a silly question but what is the difference in the way the brackets are are escaped. You used ["(\\(\\"] for the left bracket and ["\\\))"] for the right bracket.

Comment: @ziggy - Without escaping it is regex grouping - see http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: the backslash is a special charackter in a String, it is showing the String, that a special charackter will come next. Due to this you can not just write `String s = "\"` this will raise an error. you have to write `String s = `"\\".` By this the String will interpretate the special charackter "\" as a "\" and not as an identifier for a special char

Comment: Why does it ignore the last bracket in the following test: 
"2045949(50),2045949(50)".split("(\\\(\\d+\\\))?,");

Comment: @ziggy - Because it has no comma

Comment: Is it possible to make the comma optional?

Comment: @ziggy - Use `String[] list = str.split("(\\(\\d+\\))?(?:,|$)");` - see http://ideone.com/J3QtTR

Answer (score 1):

Delete all parenthesis and their values with regex first, then split the string on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to find all occurrences of the parenthesized numbers, and replace them with "", then split.